# Have dropdown menus use value of previous dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a "master dropdown menu" that contains four options (English, Spanish, Russian, Other) as the question asks their primary language.

Below this master dropdown menu contains other questions that asks similar questions and contain the same options (English, Spanish, Russian, Other).

I am wondering if it's possible to have the other dropdown menu options have the same value selected based on the 'master dropdown menu' option.  So if John Smith chooses English in the master dropdown menu, the other questions will automatically have English selected in the other dropdown menus, while also allowing John to change an Answer - he may choose Spanish for question 3.  I'm hoping the solution uses JavaScript or jQuery, as PHP won't be an option.

```html
<label>What is your primary language?</label>
<select name="question1">
  <option></option>
  <option value="english">English</option>
  <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="russian">Russian</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<label>Language your spouse speaks?</label>
<select name="question2">
  <option></option>
  <option value="english">English</option>
  <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="russian">Russian</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<label>Language your children speak?</label>
<select name="question3">
  <option></option>
  <option value="english">English</option>
  <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="russian">Russian</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When selecting the value in the master dropdown menu you can set the value to the other dropdowns via JavaScript.

`document.querySelector('select[name="question1"]').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  document.querySelector('select[name="question2"]').value = event.target.value;
  document.querySelector('select[name="question3"]').value = event.target.value;
});`

really simple solution but should work

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8sywgus3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in jQuery as follows, using nextAll() to populate the other select items:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $(this).nextAll('select').val($(this).val());
});
```

(Note that you probably want to add a class to your selects as the above will operate on ALL select elements on the page).

Answer (score 0):

Below you are adding an EventListener to to trigger when the first item is changed and assigning its value to rest of the selectors. Please update var firstDD and reminingDD valriables based on your requirement. Or better use specific IDs for each seletor so that it would be easy to understand.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var firstDD = $("select:first-child");
        var reminingDD = $("select:not(:first-child)");
        console.log(reminingDD);
        firstDD.change(function () {
            $(reminingDD).val($(firstDD).val());
        });
    });
```